# How to select and cut an entire row from sheet1 and paste it in sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

Simple table in sheet1 with data in cells(A2:C4), column D is empty. I want to select the entire row, cut and paste it in sheet2 when a time is added in colum D.
When I clicked on the logout button, It will add a time punch in column D.
I want that entire row to be selected and then cut and paste in sheet2.
I want also to arrange the remaining entry to move up so that there's no spaces between.

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

```
Dim CM As Boolean

Private Sub cmdMove_Click()

Dim myLog As Worksheet
Dim myLogSheet As Range
Dim i As Long: i = 1

Set myLog = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set myLogSheet = myLog.Range("B:B").Find(txtID.Value, , , xlWhole)

'Dim LastRow As Long
'LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
If Not myLogSheet Is Nothing Then
myLogSheet.Offset(0, 2) = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")

With ActiveSheet
For n = nLastRow To nFirstRow Step -1
        If .Cells(n, "D") = "" Then
            .Cells(n, "D").EntireRow.Cut Sheet2.Cells(i, "A")
            .Cells(n, "D").EntireRow.Delete '~~> if you want to delete
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End With
    

Else
txtName.Value = "NO RECORD"

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: If I select the ID, it will show the corresponding Name which is correct. If I click the button, a time punch will display in Column D. I want to move that entire row to sheeet2(as indicated that that employee is already logout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove your loop, and just use the row you found using the `Find`:

```
Dim CM As Boolean

Private Sub cmdMove_Click()

    Dim myLog As Worksheet
    Dim myLogSheet As Range
    Dim myLogSheetRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    'Probably you want:
    i = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Set myLog = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set myLogSheet = myLog.Range("B:B").Find(txtID.Value, , , xlWhole)

    If Not myLogSheet Is Nothing Then
        myLogSheetRow = myLogSheet.Row ' So we can delete the row later
        myLogSheet.Offset(0, 2) = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
        myLogSheet.EntireRow.Cut Sheet2.Cells(i, "A")
        myLog.Rows(myLogSheetRow).Delete
    Else
        txtName.Value = "NO RECORD"
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that Excel exhibits very odd behaviour when deleting the row after the `Cut`.  Using a statement of `myLogSheet.EntireRow.Delete` after the `Cut` causes Excel to delete the row **in Sheet1** based on the new location of the cell **in Sheet2**.  This is why a variable needs to be created to refer to the row prior to the `Cut`, so that it can be used in the `Delete` after the `Cut`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146981/discussion-between-yowe3k-and-bamboo-likefox).

Comment: Hi @YowE3k How are you doing today Sir.  I would like to revive this project.  I got a small problem though.