# EntireRow.Delete seems to delete incorrect row

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'Set some dummy data
    For r = 1 To 20
        ws1.Cells(r, "A").Value = r + 100
        ws2.Cells(r, "A").Value = r + 200
    Next

    'Set a reference to Sheet1!A11
    Set rng = ws1.Range("A11")

    'Copy Sheet1 row 11 to Sheet2 row 5
    rng.EntireRow.Cut ws2.Range("A5")

    'Delete Sheet1 row 11
    rng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

I assign a reference to a cell in row 11 of "Sheet1".  Using that reference, I `Cut` that row to a location on "Sheet2", and then I use the reference to delete the entire row from "Sheet1".

My expectation is that row 11 of "Sheet1" will be deleted, leaving values in column A of 101 to 110 in rows 1 to 10, then 112 to 120 in rows 11 to 19.

What is happening is that row 11 is being cleared (due to the `Cut`) and **row 5** is being deleted.

Image of sheets after code has executed:
[image: Image of sheets after code runs]

The fact that it is row 5 that is deleted appears to be related to the fact that row 5 is the destination row on "Sheet2" of the `Cut` statement.  And if it had deleted row 5 on "Sheet2", I could understand what was happening - i.e. that the reference was being repointed to the other sheet as part of the `Cut` - but it deletes row 5 on "Sheet1".

Can anyone explain this weird behaviour?

Note: This question was inspired by my attempts to write [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44557054/6535336), and my many comments to the OP of that question telling them "of course `EntireRow.Delete` will delete your row - why are you telling me it isn't working".

Comment: Reproduced. Holarious! I checked `?Address(external:=true)` before and after the `Cut` operation: `Sheet1!$A$11` before, `Sheet1!$A$5` after.

Comment: @A.S.H You can imagine how embarrassed I felt when I had to admit to the OP of the other question that they weren't just imagining that their code wasn't working!  :(

Comment: This is weird but not all weird. When ws1.[A11]  gets cut to ws2.[A5], thus the address of `rng` gets updated from [A11] to [A5], but the sheet name of `rng` did not get updated. So `rng.entirerow.delete` delete `ws1.[5:5]`

Comment: @Rosetta I could understand it if `rng` was pointing to `ws2.[A5]` after the `Cut`, but can't understand why it would point to `ws1.[A5]` - i.e. why would the row reference change but the sheet reference remain unchanged?  (I could even understand if `rng` became `Nothing` after the `Cut`.)

Comment: sorry @YowE3K, i don't know why either. hope someone could clarify this.

Comment: It's like the range had to migrate to its new address, but somewhere deep in the (Excel/VBA) code it was protected against changing the `Parent` worksheet. So the address changed, but not the `Parent` property. For sure it's not consistent though.

Comment: This is a `Excel` bug. But not the address migration at all is the bug, but **not** migrating the external address part is the bug. So even after fixing this bug, `rng` will not be the same after cutting the entire row, containing `rng`, and pasting it to a new destination. So what?

Comment: Conclusion: the Range's address property is mutable, but the Parent property is immutable. We were on an edge case were these two specs were in conflict, hence the inconsistency.

Comment: I think that the main use-case behind making the range's address mutable is the `Insert` operation. `Cut` looks to me a marginal one.

Comment: @AxelRichter Do you know whether it is documented as a bug anywhere?

Comment: No, I don't know. But what I'm trying to say is, that the bug is not relevant to the problem. You **must** remember the sheet and the row number from where you have cut and then have pasted to somewhere else, if you wants to delete that row then.

Comment: I can reproduce it also with the latest Office 365 Excel update. Interesting that if you execute a `Range.Copy`, `rng` does not change and `.EntireRow.Delete` works on the desired row.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: Copy/paste is totally different from cut/paste. The first is duplicating the cells. So the source range address does not need changing since it is still there. The second is moving the cells. So the source range address should move to the destination also.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks.  Not being familiar with the inner workings of Excel, I did not realize that the source range address had to move also.  I would have thought only the contents of the cell would have to move.

Comment: The `Cut` method returns a new object - See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.cut.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1 However - as to why this range object still points to ws1 is strange. 
After the cut if you check `rng.Worksheet.Name` you'll see it didn't actually return the object you'd expect. Seems like an Excel bug to me.

Comment: @RikSportel - Very interesting - but if you try to assign the return value to an object (e.g. Dim rng2 As Object: Set rng2 = rng.EntireRow.Cut(ws2.Range("A5"))`) it crashes with an object required error.  (Maybe Interop works differently to normal VBA??)

Comment: Yes, if you check the VBA reference, the return value is a type variant. If you do `dim returnval as variant` and then `returnval = rng.EntireRow.Cut(ws2.Range("A5"))` you'll see it's a Boolean set to true. The thing is this system.object is in the original range object (rng). It's still a riddle to me why this rng object is not pointing to ws2.

Answer (score 1):

use "copy" instead of "cut"

**rng.EntireRow.Copy ws2.Range("A5")**

the line at sheet1 A11 does not have to be empty when you delete it

here is a simpler version that shows the undesired behaviour

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A11")
    rng.Value = "cut and paste me"

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A11").Cut Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A5")  ' rng object not used in this line

    rng.Select     ' selects Sheet1 A5  ...  it should be Sheet2 A5

End Sub
```

it appears to be a bug in excel

since the cut/paste effectively moves the cut range, excel moves the reference to the new location

excel moves the reference to the correct cell, but it fails to move to the correct worksheet

the reference is moved correctly if you do the cut/paste by hand

for example:

if, sheet1 cell A1 contains  "=B1"

and you cut sheet1 cell B1 and paste it to sheet2 cell C3

then sheet1 cell A1 will contain "=sheet2!C3"

Comment: "the reference is moved correctly if you do the cut/paste by hand" - even when done via VBA, the formulas are automatically updated.  (E.g. adding a line saying `ws1.Range("C7").Formula = "=A11"` prior to the cut in the question's code will leave Sheet1!C7 with a formula of `=Sheet2!A5` after the cut.)  So it seems to be just the `Range` object that has issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try my code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'Set some dummy data
    For r = 1 To 20
        ws1.Cells(r, "A").Value = r + 100
        ws2.Cells(r, "A").Value = r + 200
    Next

    'Set a reference to Sheet1!A11
    Set rng = ws1.Range("A11")

    'Copy Sheet1 row 11 to Sheet2 row 5
    rng.EntireRow.Cut ws2.Range("A5")

    'Delete Sheet1 row 11
    Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete


End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't resolve the question of why `rng` is not referring to the original range on "Sheet1", or to some new range on "Sheet2", but instead refers to a new range on "Sheet1".  And that code will delete all rows in the ActiveSheet (which might be "Sheet1". or "Sheet2". or even "Sheet3") where column A is blank, irrespective of whether other columns contain data.

Answer (score 0):

As @A.S.H mentioned, `Debug.Print rng.Address(external:=True)` before and after the `Cut` operation will print the result `[workbookName.xlsm]Sheet1!$A$11` and `[workbookName.xlsm]Sheet1!$A$5` respectively, the reason is that it cuts the object and pastes into a specified destination and acquires its address.

Range Object being a member of the Worksheet Object, can't change its parent and so it continues to remain as a member of `ws1`. Therefore, trying `ws2.rng.EntireRow.Delete` will generate compile error "Method or data member not found".

Answer (score 0):

**Possible explication** - but no excuse for this not obvious comportment:

1) *Why not changing the sheet, too?* -
    The `.Cut` method overwrites only the **`Range`** definition because it is
    subordinated to the `Worksheet` object set via `ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")`,
    thus the `ws1` object only gets a new target range $A$5 but remains the original sheet

2) *Why changing the source range to target?* -
    IMO sort of minimalism within the method code itself.

3) *What is to do* - **reset the original range** (see code below):

```
Sub test()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim r As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

'Set some dummy data
For r = 1 To 20
    ws1.Cells(r, "A").Value = r + 100
    ws2.Cells(r, "A").Value = r + 200
Next


' Set a reference to Sheet1!A11
  Set rng = ws1.Range("A11")
' Copy Sheet1 row 11 to Sheet2 row 5
  rng.EntireRow.Cut ws2.Range("A5")

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' Possible explication - but no excuse for this not obvious comportment:
' 1) Why not changing the sheet, too? -
'    The CUT method overwrites only the RANGE definition because it is
'    subordinated to the worksheet object set via ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1"),
'    thus the ws1 object only gets a new target range $A$5 but remains the original sheet
' 2) Why changing the source range to target? -
'    IMO sort of minimalism within the method code itself.
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' >> check range definition after executing CUT - rng definitively remains in sheet1
  MsgBox "Range rng: " & rng.Worksheet.Name & "!" & rng.Address & vbNewLine & _
         "Entire row: " & rng.EntireRow.Address & " ", vbInformation, "rng.Address"

' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
' If you want to do something with the original range you have to reset it
' ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 ' >> reset rng before further action as deleting source
  Set rng = ws1.Range("A11")      ' << resetting rng necessary

' Delete Sheet1 row 11
  rng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```